# Passing values from an object inside a function

Tags: javascript, function, object, arguments, parameter-passing

I have been working all day trying to pass the value of "returnData.salary" inside the "readData" function to
the object inside the "calculateTax" function which is suppose to take the salary value and calculate state and federal taxes. I am stumped, I can't find anything on the internet which provides a good example for me to work with. The examples are either way to simple or super complex. Any help would be appreciated.

I apologize in advance if I did not submit this question in the correct format. This is my first time asking for help on stackoverflow.

```
function readForm() {

        var returnData = {};
        returnData.name = $("#name").val();
        returnData.lastName = $("#lastName").val();
        returnData.age = $("#age").val();
        returnData.gender = $("[name=gender]:checked").val();
        returnData.salary = $("#salary").val();
        returnData.isManager = $("#isManager").val();
        returnData.myTextArea = $("#myTextArea").val();

        $("#name2").text(returnData.name);
        $("#lastName2").text(returnData.lastName);
        $("#age2").text(returnData.age);
        $("#gender2").text(returnData.gender);
        $("#salary2").text(returnData.salary);
        $("#myTextArea2").text(returnData.myTextArea);

        if ($(isManager).is(':checked')) {

            $("#isManager2").text("Yes");
        }
        else {
            $("#isManager2").text("No");
        }

        //$("#employeeForm")[0].reset();


    } //end of readForm function 

    function calculateTax() {

        console.log("Button Works");

    var calculateTax = {
        state: function(num) {
            num *= 0.09;
            return num;
        }
        , federal: function(num) {
            if (num > 10000) {
                num *= 0.2;
                return num;
            }
            else {
                num * 0.1;
                return num;
            }

        }
        , exempt: true
    };

    }

    //Invoke readForm function when the submit button is clicked.

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnSubmit").on("click", readForm);
        $("#btnCalculate").on("click", calculateTax);
    })

</script>
```

Comment: How do I pass the object values inside function to another function which also contains objects?

Comment: Store the data outside the functions will do

Answer (score 1):

Well, simply put; you can't. Not like this anyway. Or, at least not pass the value to the function directly.

You are using global functions right now, which are not inside a class. If it was inside a class, you could instantiate the class and save it to `this` (which would be the class' instance). However, I'm assuming classes are a bit over complicated in this case. What you could do, is set variables globally so all functions can use them, like this;

```
//declare the global variable so it exists for every function     
var returnData = {};

function readForm() {

        //We do NOT redeclare the "var" again. It's global now.
        returnData = {}; //Reset the global variable when this function is called
        returnData.name = $("#name").val();
        returnData.lastName = $("#lastName").val();
        returnData.age = $("#age").val();
        returnData.gender = $("[name=gender]:checked").val();
        returnData.salary = $("#salary").val();
        returnData.isManager = $("#isManager").val();
        returnData.myTextArea = $("#myTextArea").val();

       //Rest of your function
}
function calculateTax(){
  console.log(returnData) //works here
}
```

Note that you do overwrite global variables, so it's best to reset them on every function call. You might get old data stuck in there, otherwise.